# Any Stable version of Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am looking forward to start with Android studio, its a bit too irritating

previously I tried the same around 3-4 months back but didn't continued using since it wasn't stable (as I read in documents)

Now I wish to start with setup on linux Mint

I keep on getting errors

```
Gradle project sync failed. Please fix your project and try again.
```

My build.gradle file is always empty

Also, I am using version 0.4.6 is that an issue with gradle version

I have already tried deleting .gradle folder from my home directory

Any help please

Comment: I am also waiting for this to be stable. Eclipse sucks!! specially when migrating projects between different machines :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no stable version yet, but you should update it. Today (2014-08-20) is 0.8.10 the newset version. Show us your build.gradle to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: thanks for response @rekire, my build.gradle was empty, Now I am able to fix that by changing gradle version in wrapper

Comment: The build.gradle of your module must not be empty. Gradle will not know what to do. However keep in mind that you have always two of the build files one per project and one per module.